# Unwanted update to Created Field in Sitecore TDS item

Tags: tds

I am using Sitecore 8.2. For some reason, my local instance updates the created field at the top in TDS item (highlighted in snapshot). I know this is not the Sitecore item created date field which is represented by __Created (also in snapshot). I have looked around but havent found much information on what this field represents and why is it updated on my local. Appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this if anyone has similar queries in future. Sitecore support answered that-

- Created field values are updated by Sitecore serialization. TDS doesn't directly update them, it uses the Serialization API to get the item and it is changed/updated by the API
- Created field is ignored by TDS for sync and compare. It was not present in older versions of Sitecore, therefore, we don't use it to maintain backward compatibility. Since it is ignored by TDS, there is not much information about the field, but it has not caused any problems with any of the users.
- Created field shows up as a difference in compare window, because it is different. When looking for differences, the sync window does not look at that property, and will not flag an item as different if there are no field differences.